# MSBuild error CS2001 source file could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command-line, msbuild

I'm trying to do a command line build on one of my projects using MSbuild. The solution and project builds fine in VS2012, but when I execute a batch file containing

```
msbuild.exe project.csproj
```

It fails. There are so many errors I cant even scroll up past them. They are all the same error, for different files, all from other projects in the solution:

```
CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'folder\filename.cs' cound not be found [c:\folder\project.csproj]
```

I have found other questions talking about file name lengths. I tried removing every layer in the path that I could, to no avail. I find it odd that the source file path is not relative, even though the files it can't find are, indeed, from other projects. i'm at a bit of a loss here. Why does my build fail?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're executing a batch file.  Where is this batch file located in reference to the project you intend to build, and can you post the batch file contents (sans any proprietary information)?

Comment: +1 To Nick. This is likely a file path issue. It works fine for me (the path i'm passing into msbuild is also a relative path) Also, why are other projects in the solution building? Are they being referenced by project.csproj?

Comment: MsBuild will build referenced projects prior to building dependencies.

Comment: if you are using TFS then you can simply undo cs.proj file, mine issue fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, while this may not actually be the same problem others are seeing, I solved my specific problem:

The project in question is an MVC 4 project. MVC has an option you can enable in the project file that builds the razor views as part of the compilation process, ostensibly so you can catch what would normally be run time errors at build time.

This feature has not been particularly well supported, and when you build from command line, it starts looking for things in weird places as it is doing these intermediate builds. The views get built in temp directories, then it attempts to copy it from the project directories, then everything falls apart.

In addition, we need to know the solution dir for some post build events, but that will be irrelevant to most people. We also build to a package, then deploy directly to make it easier to copy stuff out to the various places it needs to go. Building as a package also properly resolves all the solution references the project may have, for more complex projects. I included it here for completions sake.

Here is the line that has it all working properly:

```
msbuild.exe /v:q  projectName.csproj /t:Package /p:MvcBuildViews=false;SolutionDir=%SolutionDir%;DeployOnBuild=true
```

and the simple version that really fixed the problem:

```
msbuild.exe projectName.csproj /p:MvcBuildViews=false;
```

Comment: I feel bad accepting my own answer, but hopefully people with my exact problem will be happy with this solution

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the projects were created for the solution so when you try to build outside of the solution, they break as the solution was the glue that resolved the location of all the projects.

If you build the solution from the command line, does it work?

```
msbuild.exe solutionname.sln
```

If so, close Visual Studio, open Notepad++ and get ready to start editing some XML!

**Eliminate the use of absolute paths, preferring paths relative from the solution root folder.**

First, Create a common properties folder in the root of your enlistment called "Common.props" and add the following markup:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SlnRoot>$( [MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory), Common.props ) )</SlnRoot>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, add this markup to every member project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CommonPropsFolder>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) ,Common.props))</CommonPropsFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(CommonPropsFolder)\Common.props" />
```

(This should be the first XML node to appear following the <Project /> node)

Now find all the <ProjectReference /> nodes in affected .csproj files.  Modify the reference so that the path is relative to the solution root and prefixed with the new $(SrcRoot) MsBuild property.

e.g. 
From

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Tools\Build\Common.csproj">
  <Project>{deadbeef-dead-beef-dead-beefdeadbeef}</Project>
  <Name>Common</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

To

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(SlnRoot)\Tools\Build\Common.csproj">
  <Project>{deadbeef-dead-beef-dead-beefdeadbeef}</Project>
  <Name>Common</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Now test to make sure you can build by specifying the solution name, then navigate to and compile an individual project.